# Calculating teams goals for season from JSON data (nested objects)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

How can I get a teams goals scored for the season from the following data. Where the teams name is the function input.

Am I correct in trying to map over the rounds and filter the matches where team1 or team 2 === inputted team then reduce the sum of those scores?

Shortened sample of data:

```
{
  "name": "English Premier League 2014/15",
  "rounds": [
    {
      "name": "Matchday 1",
      "matches": [
        {
          "date": "2014-08-16",
          "team1": {
            "key": "manutd",
            "name": "Manchester United",
            "code": "MUN"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "swansea",
            "name": "Swansea",
            "code": "SWA"
          },
          "score1": 1,
          "score2": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "2014-08-16",
          "team1": {
            "key": "leicester",
            "name": "Leicester City",
            "code": "LEI"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "everton",
            "name": "Everton",
            "code": "EVE"
          },
          "score1": 2,
          "score2": 2
        },
```

My effort so far is:

```
function run (teamName){

    function getSum (total, match) {
        return total + match.score1;
    }


    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2014-15/en.1.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.rounds.map( matchday => matchday.matches.filter(match => match.team1.name === teamName).reduce(getSum))));

}

run('Liverpool')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function findScoreByTeamName(strTeamName){

  let jsnLeague = {
    "name": "English Premier League 2014/15",
    "rounds": [
      {
        "name": "Matchday 1",
        "matches": [
          {
            "date": "2014-08-16",
            "team1": {
              "key": "manutd",
              "name": "Manchester United",
              "code": "MUN"
            },
            "team2": {
              "key": "swansea",
              "name": "Swansea",
              "code": "SWA"
            },
            "score1": 1,
            "score2": 2
          },
          {
            "date": "2014-08-16",
            "team1": {
              "key": "leicester",
              "name": "Leicester City",
              "code": "LEI"
            },
            "team2": {
              "key": "everton",
              "name": "Everton",
              "code": "EVE"
            },
            "score1": 2,
            "score2": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  let score = 0;

  for(round of jsnLeague.rounds){
      for(match of round.matches){
          if(match.team1.name == strTeamName){
              score += match.score1;
          }else if(match.team2.name == strTeamName){
              score += match.score2;
          }
      }
  }

  console.log(score);

}

//Then call it
findScoreByTeamName("Swansea");
```

I have tested the code [here](https://playcode.io/online-javascript-editor), copy-paste it and give it a look

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! But when I insert the following fetch request I get error 'objLeague.rounds is not iterable at findScoreByTeamName '                                                                                                                                                                 let objLeague =   fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2014-15/en.1.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })

Comment: @Richjames I have modified the answer to improve it, try it again replacing the "jsnLeague" object! And at the end I added a link where you can test the code

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know how to combine with a fetch call to retrieve the data instead of hard coded object?  i.e get the data using fetch then run the for loops

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in a sort of functional programming way. You'll find comments directly above function expression declarations:

```js
const JSON_ORIGIN = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2014-15/en.1.json'

const download = () =>
  fetch(JSON_ORIGIN).then(response => response.json())

const sum = (total, value) => total + value

// get the score comparing first and second team
const resultPerMatch = teamName => match => {
  if (match.team1.name === teamName) return match.score1
  if (match.team2.name === teamName) return match.score2
  
  // if the chosen team didn't played this game, it gets 0 points
  return 0
}

// given a round, sum the scores of this team for each match
const resultsPerRound = teamName => round =>
  round.matches.map(resultPerMatch(teamName)).reduce(sum, 0)

// given a team, sum the scores for each round
const resultsPerTeam = (data, teamName) => {
  return data.rounds.map(resultsPerRound(teamName)).reduce(sum, 0)
}

// wait until data gets downloaded
download().then(data => {
  console.log(resultsPerTeam(data, 'Manchester United'))  // 62
  console.log(resultsPerTeam(data, 'Liverpool'))          // 52
})
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried retrieving the data as you did but using the for loops from the 2nd solution. I keep getting error: rounds not defined even tho i console.log(data.rounds) before the for loop and can see the array. My code is:

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using a mix of both solutions above to retrieve data and using for loops. Thanks for your help

```
const getTeamScore = async (teamName) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2014-15/en.1.json');
    const json = await response.json();



let score = 0;

for(round of json.rounds){
  for(match of round.matches){
    if(match.team1.name === teamName){ 
     score += match.score1
    }else if(match.team2.name === teamName){
     score += match.score2
    }else{
      score = score
    }

  }

 }

   console.log('Total goals scored for the season by ' + teamName + ' were: ' + score )

}



getTeamScore('Manchester United');
```